# Rails : how to set a controller to NOT use devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm building a website using Ruby on Rails and Devise and want to exclude some basic controllers from the access control, like home, about, contact, etc... how do I set a controller that I don't want that devise to apply access control on it?

Answer (score 1):

[Controller filters and helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Assuming you've added `before_action :authenticate_user!` or similar to your application_controller.rb (and any subsequent base controllers),

`skip_before_action :authenticate_user!`